Splitting Worksheet on Excel based on keyword which is available in one column
I have one master excel file. I have to split the excel file into another excel files based on one keyword which is available in one single column.
And the rest data (excluded that keyword) will be splitted to other one.
Example :

I have data in Sheet1. Keyword "HN" is available randomly in column AB like
I have to move all row contains the keyword in column F into Sheet2 (name HN).
Thanks
KL
Can we have VBA code to help this problem?
Thank you in advance.
Adding VBA code I used
It works 99%.
for example: as image, row 2&3 merged. The problem is row 2&3 will be unmerged, and it will not move row 3 as this image

Can we revise the code, to move all row merged if they met the condition?
Sub Movedata()
Dim ListOfWords As Range, ListWord As Range, EndRw As Long, DltRng As Range
Set ListOfWords = Range("AB1:AB" & Cells(Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row)
EndRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
For Each ListWord In ListOfWords
  For Each Rng In Range("F2:F" & EndRw)
    If InStr(Rng, ListWord) Then
      Rng.Offset(, -5).Resize(, 22).Copy Sheets("HN").Cut Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)(2)
      If DltRng Is Nothing Then
        Set DltRng = Rng.Offset(, -5).Resize(, 22)
      Else
        Set DltRng = Union(DltRng, Rng.Offset(, -5).Resize(, 22))
      End If
    End If
  Next Rng
Next ListWord
If Not DltRng Is Nothing Then DltRng.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub


Question: Do you need the cells merged? If they are only merged so you don't show the duplicate values, unmerge them and "hide" the duplicated with conditional formatting. With that, code will be much easier

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.

n = rng.MergeArea.Rows.Count tells you how many rows are merged in ColF, so that's how many rows you need to copy using something like Rng.Offset(, -5).Resize(n, 22).Copy  (and add that same area to DltRng)

Using VBA you could do something like this:
Sub MoveWords()
    Dim ListOfWords As Range, ListWord As Range, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'or a specific named sheet
    Set ListOfWords = ws.Range("AB1:AB" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    For Each ListWord In ListOfWords
        MoveRowsWithWord ListWord.Value
    Next ListWord
End Sub

Sub MoveRowsWithWord(wd As String)
    Const COL_CHECK As String = "D"
    Dim EndRw As Long, DltRng As Range, ws As Worksheet, n As Long, rw As Range, c As Range
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'or specific named sheet
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HN")
    
    EndRw = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, COL_CHECK).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set rw = ws.Range("A2").Resize(1, 10)
    Do While rw.Row <= EndRw
        Set c = rw.Columns(COL_CHECK)
        n = c.MergeArea.Rows.Count
        If InStr(c.Value, wd) > 0 Then
            rw.Resize(n).Copy wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            BuildRange DltRng, rw.Resize(n)
        End If
        Set rw = rw.Offset(n) 'move down `n` rows
    Loop
    'delete any copied rows
    If Not DltRng Is Nothing Then DltRng.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub

'add range `rngAdd` to range `rngTot`
Sub BuildRange(ByRef rngTot As Range, rngAdd As Range)
    If rngTot Is Nothing Then
        Set rngTot = rngAdd
    Else
        Set rngTot = Application.Union(rngTot, rngAdd)
    End If
End Sub

Deleting copied rows after each word prevents from accidentally copying the same row multiple times if it happens to match >1 item in your list.

Assuming I understand your problem correctly, you can use Power Query to solve your problem.  Define your table as a named range, for example name it "Table" and import it into Power Query.  In Power Query, select the column which had merged cells and use the fill down function.
Example input:

Power Query code:
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table"]}[Content],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"A", Int64.Type}, {"B", Int64.Type}, {"C", type text}, {"D", type number}}),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Changed Type",{"A", "B", "C"})
in
    #"Filled Down"

As this stage you can filter the columns as required.
Output:


Use a Dict object to consolidate all data rows for each item in Column F, then split the rows into a new worksheet.
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey, rngRows As Range
    Dim arrData, ColCnt As Long
    Const KEY_COL = "F" ' modify as needed
    Dim oSht1 As Worksheet, oSht2 As Worksheet
    Set oSht1 = Sheets("Sheet1") ' source table, modify as needed
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ColCnt = oSht1.Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
    ' load data into an array
    Set rngData = oSht1.Range("F2", oSht1.Cells(oSht1.Rows.Count, KEY_COL).End(xlUp))
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ' get the range (multi-areas) for each item on Col F
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 1)
        If Len(sKey)>0 Then
            Set rngRows = oSht1.Cells(i + 1, 1).MergeArea.Resize(, ColCnt)
            If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
                Set objDic(sKey) = Union(objDic(sKey), rngRows)
            Else
                Set objDic(sKey) = rngRows
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    ' interate itmes
    For Each sKey In objDic.Keys
        If IsSheetExist(sKey) Then
            ' clear existing sheet
            Set oSht2 = Sheets(sKey)
            oSht2.Cells.Clear
        Else
            ' add new sheet
            Set oSht2 = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
            oSht2.Name = sKey
        End If
        ' copy header row
        oSht1.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, ColCnt).Copy oSht2.Cells(1, 1)
        ' copy data rows
        objDic(sKey).Copy oSht2.Cells(2, 1)
    Next
End Sub

Function IsSheetExist(ByVal ShtName As String) As Boolean
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ShtName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    IsSheetExist = Not (Sht Is Nothing)
End Function


